# StackView change to match device orientation

Tags: ios

Is it possible to use a vertical stack view when the device is in portrait mode, but switch to a horizontal stack view when the device is orientated to landscape mode, to make best use of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Auto Layout to design UI, orientation will be taken care of  automatically.

See a tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views), it should answer your question in detail.

Comment: I think the correct approach is as stated, using  Auto Layout correctly rather than changing StackView orientation directly

Comment: When using auto layout, the stack view is still either horizontal or vertical, it doesn't automatically switch between the two

Comment: Using class traits you can alter the orientation e.g. from vertical to horizontal  for compact height.

Answer (score 4):

Click the small plus button in the attributes inspector to add a variation, in this screenshot I already added one to switch to horizontal when regular width.

[image]

See a preview by changing the screen options at the bottom of the storyboard.

Comment: "regular" and "compact" are note suitable for detecting the device's orientation. Eg. on a horizontally placed iPad, its height is still regular.